# Angular ng-click function doesn't always fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an Angular ng-click function that doesn't always fire.

URL is here: http://430designs.com/xperience/black-label-app/deck.php

The function is clickLike here:

```
$scope.clickLike = function() {
      $('.icon-like').on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('happy');
      });
    };
```

I'm calling it in the HTML like so:

```
<div class="icon-like" ng-click="clickLike()"</div>
```

Check the link and you can debug in controller.js line 214.  I'm not sure what's going on.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the onclick method inside `$scope.clickLike`

```
<div class="icon-like" ng-click="clickLike($event)"</div>

$scope.clickLike = function(e) {
  e.currentTarget.toggleClass('happy');
});
```

e.currentTarget will be the element that triggers the event.

You also need to pass `$event` in you ng-click directive:

Here's an example: http://www.freedevelopertutorials.com/angularjs-tutorial/examples/angularjs-event-example/

Comment: don't we need to pass `$event` in ng-click function and capture in the scope function ?

Comment: @A.J sorry I forgot that one. But hey, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Thanks @A.J. However, just using currentTarget.toggleClass() isn't working. `currentTarget` isn't defined. Sorry, I'm still learning angular. Thoughts?

Comment: @lz430 instead of currentTarget, you need to use `$event.target`

Comment: Thanks @A.J. Now I'm getting `e.currentTarget.toggleClass is not a function` Am I doing something wrong. I copied your code exactly

Comment: I ended up getting it. I had to wrap it with a jQuery selector. Final code: `$scope.clickLike = function(e) {
          $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('happy');
        }; //clickLike`

Comment: @lz430 same as my answer but you used jQuery for it while my answer used native language. Btw, glad you got it :)

Comment: It kept throwing an error with what you had. Not sure why. I'm very eager to learn why though. I'd much rather use the native Angular language as I'm still learning. :)

Comment: @lz430 : Avoid using jQuery in Angular project, angular already offers jQuery lite. Please see I have added an answer in that capture event using $event.target and then use angular.element to get element and then you can toggle class. This would be the angular way to code.

Comment: Dont tightly couple your controller to your dom... use directives it is angular best practice. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller  I included a plunkr and an explanation in your question.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to use a **directive** to manipulate your **DOM**... it is not best practice to manipulate DOM from the controller.  Check this example out, I created a directive that is used as an attribute (just like ng-click) and applies a class to the element where this directive is an attribute of.

From the angular site:

> **Use controllers to:**
>
> - Set up the initial state of the $scope object
> - Add behavior to the $scope object.
>
> **Do not use controllers to:**
>
> - Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic.    Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects 
>     its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation.
> - Format input —    Use angular form controls instead.
> - Filter output — Use  angular    filters instead. Share code or state across controllers — Use angular    services instead.
> - Manage the life-cycle of other components (for    example, to create service instances).

Let me know if this helps:  https://plnkr.co/edit/hyS5yxwajbJKSFYylKDw?p=preview

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
  .directive('clickLike', [clickLike])
  .controller('HomeController', [HomeController]);

function clickLike() {

    var self = {};

    self.restrict = 'A';
    self.link = linkFn;

    return self;

    function linkFn($scope, $element, $attributes) {

        $element.on('click', function(event) {

        $element.toggleClass('happy');

    });

  }

}

function HomeController() {

    var self = this;

    self.message = "Hello World!";

}
```

In your html you can use this directive in any element..not tightly couple to your controller..

`<div class="icon-like" click-like></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `$event` and capture `$event` in the click event. Then you can use `$event.target` to access the element.

Example Snippet:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.clickLike = function($event) {
      angular.element($event.target).toggleClass("hello")
    }
  })
```

```css
.hello {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-like" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-click="clickLike($event)">Hello</div>
```